# Japanese fonts in WineHQ?

Tags: macos, wine

I'm trying to play some old japanese classics that use Windows-only fonts like MS Gothic using WineHQ, and I'm finding that because these fonts are not available they default to system ones that aren't properly rendered on screen.

I have tried exporting `LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8`, which fixes some fonts but not all of them.

Is there any way to install and configure these fonts to work with all software?

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are the same and the way to install them also pretty much the same in Windows or any major Linux distro.

Knowing that, why didn't you install all the fonts you need already?

In Ubuntu and derivatives there's already a package providing all the typical TTF you'd find in Windows (including "MS Gothic"): `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, also part of the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package and other similar ones, but any required font can be installed separately.

Comment: I don't believe this is about which fonts are installed in the system, but rather how WineHQ emulates them. I do have MSGothic installed, and it's not being picked up.

Comment: If so, you need to do this: https://wiki.winehq.org/Font_Replacements